# ASP.NET MVC: Hierarhical roles, custom authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, roles

Is there a way to organize the roles in my app like a tree? You know, User can do several things, Moderator is just like user but can do little more, Administator have even more abilitities, etc. I've found nothing in the "Web Site Administration Tool".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make it a tree for that.

Remember the same user can have multiple roles. When u need to give those extra permissions, u enable the extra role(s) to that user.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to get along :)